# Inspecting/Evaluating an expression in java library .class file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, java-8

How can I inspect or evaluate an expression in a method of java class, like for example `java.io.File`, in Eclipse?

I know how to debug, but I cannot evaluate an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Window > Show View > Display` and enter statements there.

Also read this manual: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-14.htm

Comment: i tried your approach while debugging the following method 'java.io.File.createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory) ' but while evaluating prefix.length i got the error 'prefix cannot be resolved ', do you know any other way ?

Comment: I tried hovering , inspect , watch ,display none of them works , is there any work around for this

Comment: @Learner `prefix.length()` not `prefix.length` do I need to say? Also, maybe you can't read prefix because it is an external code (Java Library, not your code). Can you please try it on your own code?

Comment: prefix.length was a typo here , but my primary requirement is debugging java library code as mentioned in the description of the issue above , i.e how can i debug java library code ?

Comment: @Learner Well, I guess you can't.

Comment: @Learner Perhaps you can use Java JDK with it's source code, not binary. So you have the code, perhaps you can evaluate the expressions as usual.

Comment: @Learner But normally, you shouldn't need to debug libraries. I think you are doing something wrong. What's your problem?

Comment: Iam using jdk source code , which is coming as .class file in eclipse , anyways thanks i will do some more investigation and let you know

Comment: @Learner I think you should think about why do you want to debug library code. I guess it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `prefix.length()` as mentioned in a comment is: the debugger may not know anything about `prefix` because this name is not stored in the class file (depending on a compiler option). See that the Variables view will just show `arg0` and `arg1` - indicating that the runtime has no names for these. Other than this restriction, libraries with attached source can be debugged like normal and also evaluating expressions that don't involve local variables should work (e.g., using the `Display` view as suggested in the the answer by Salbot).